# How to load a Pandas DataFrame from a csv/tsv as factorize category type?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a huge TSV (genomic) dataset (1GB size) which has 2,504 rows and 220,001 columns. (takes 1h 11min 4s to load with `pd.read_table("biallelic-only.raw")`.

All the columns, but 5 of them, are categorical data, and I want to convert them to factorize category.

With small samples, this code addresses well:

```
data = pd.read_table("biallelic-only.raw")
categorical_feats = [
    f for f in data.columns if f not in ['FID', 'IID', 'PAT', 'MAT', 'bmi']
]

categorical_feats
for f in categorical_feats:
    data[f], _ = pd.factorize(data[f])
    data[f] = data[f].astype('category')
```

But with this huge one, it takes ages.

My question is, is it possible to load the dataset already as factoriezed categories, instead of converting it later on?

I know we can do things like:

```
pd.read_csv('file', dtype={'col_name':type}))
```

But, given I have 220,001 columns, it's not possible to set all them to a dtype dictionary. I'm wondering if there's an inverted type assignment way. Something like: set all columns as `category` except those 5 ones).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the data as categorical and specify a converter for the *exception* columns, for example, assuming a toy file named `'data.csv'` with the following data:

```
name  type   cost
AB     B      1
CV     G      4
54     B      31
AB     B      2
```

You could do:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', dtype='category', converters={'cost': int}, delim_whitespace=True)
print(df.dtypes)
```

**Output**

```
name    category
type    category
cost       int64
dtype: object
```

In the example above cost is the exception column, in your case it should be `['FID', 'IID', 'PAT', 'MAT', 'bmi']`. Note that the converters dictionary will depended on your type of data (in the example `cost` is an  integer column).

Comment: Thanks! It worked, although doesn't apply the `pd.factorize(data[f])`. I guess there's no way, but iterating over each column and applying the `factorize` function.